# Multiple highcharts charts dynamically created in angular2 on one page

Tags: angular, highcharts

Is it possible to iterate through data and create a chart for each iteration within angular2?

Using [angular2-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts) I have to follow the concept below to create a chart on a page and populate it with data.

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { CHART_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2-highcharts';

@Component({
    selector: 'simple-chart-example',
    directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
        <chart [options]="options"></chart>
    `
})
export class SimpleChartExample {
    constructor() {
        this.options = {
            title : { text : 'simple chart' },
            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
            }]
        };
    }
    options: Object;
}
```

Is it possible to create something that will loop through data and create a new `<chart [options]="options"></chart>` html line for each data item? If this is even the best way to do this.

In my scenario, I am looking to iterate through about twelve (can vary) potential charts and display them on the screen. The limitation in the above scenario is that I need to declare an options object in the SimpleChartExample class for every chart I want to display.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { CHART_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2-highcharts';

@Component({
    selector: 'simple-chart-example',
    directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES],
    template: "give your template url"
})
export class SimpleChartExample {
    constructor() {
        this.chart1 = {
            title : { text : 'simple chart' },
            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
            }]
        };
this.chart2 = {
            title : { text : 'simple chart' },
            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
            }]
        };
    }
    chart1: Object;
    chart2: Object;
}
```

and in html use this

```
<chart [options]="chart1"></chart>
<chart [options]="chart2"></chart>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the selector references to display each component. For example, a dashboard.html page could look something like below where each selector references its own component, [check out this example](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin/tree/master/src/app/pages/dashboard).

```
<div id="chart1">
    <chart-one></chart-one>
</div>

<div id="chart2">
    <chart-two></chart-two>
</div>
```

And if you need to update other graphs depending on click actions, simply use observables to capture event triggers.